# How to fix internal or external command errors in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

It builds fine, but when netbeans tries to start the emulator, the following error occurs:

> *'Blackberry' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.*

I'm searching for a general solution. Because I found many of the same type of errors on the net (But each one without an answer).

> *'xxx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.*

So how do you make Netbeans recognize 'xxx'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the path to your executable to your system path variable .

it will look at those path while executing any executable if executable found from any of those path it OR from current dir it will execute otherwise it will throw the same error.

For **Linux** you have

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/path/to/executable
```

for **windows** you will have something like ,edit it. follow [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) tutorial for more info
[image]