# how to start stop tomcat server using CMD?

Tags: java, apache, batch-file, tomcat, environment-variables

I set the path for the tomcat and set all variables like

1. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22`
2. `CATALINA_HOME=G:\springwork\server\apache-tomcat-6.0.29`
3. `CLASSPATH=G:\springwork\server\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\lib\servlet-api.jar;G:\springwork\server\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\lib\jsp-api.jar;.;`

When I go to bin folder and double click on startup.bat then my tomcat starts and when I double click on shutdown.bat tomcat stops.

But I want using CMD start and stop the tomcat.
And in any folder I write command `startup.bat` the server will start and when I write `shutdown.bat` the server will stop.

Comment: Does anyone else this is a 'superuser.com' question?

Comment: follow all steps which i define at question posted area. And then last step which tell Mr Arun in answer area.I hope you problem will be solved as like me.....

Comment: Perhaps accept Arun's answer?

Comment: maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559371/tomcat-startup-bat-is-missing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `%CATALINA_HOME%/bin` to path system variable.

Go to `Environment Variables` screen under `System Variables` there will be a `Path` variable edit the variable and add `;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin` to the variable then click `OK` to save the changes. Close all opened command prompts then open a new command prompt and try to use the command `startup.bat`.

Comment: add new variable name path and then put this value there?

Comment: @ali Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439641/how-to-fix-internal-or-external-command-errors-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 5):

Steps  to start Apache Tomcat using cmd:
1. Firstly check that the JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME is a variable available in environment variables.(If it is not create a new variable JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME)
2. Goto cmd and change your working directory to bin path where apache is installed (or extracted). 
3. Type Command -> `catalina.bat start` to **start** the server.
4. Type Command -> `catalina.bat stop` to **stop** the server.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used to start and stop tomcat 7.0.29, using ant 1.8.2. Works fine for me, but leaves the control in the started server window. I have not tried it yet, but I think if I change the "/K" in the startup sequence to "/C", it may not even do that.

```
<target name="tomcat-stop">
    <exec dir="${appserver.home}/bin" executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/C start cmd.exe /C shutdown.bat"/>
    </exec>
</target>



<target name="tomcat-start" depends="tomcat-stop" >
    <exec dir="${appserver.home}/bin" executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/K start cmd.exe /C startup.bat"/>
    </exec>

</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this trick to run tomcat using cmd and directly by tomcat bin folder.

1.
set the path of jdk.

2.

To set path.
go to Desktop and right click on computer icon.
Click the Properties

go to Advance System Settings.

then Click Advance to Environment variables.

Click new and set path AS,

in the column **Variable name=JAVA_HOME**

**Variable Value=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19**

Click ok ok.

now path is setted.

3.

Go to tomcat folder where you installed the tomcat.
go to bin folder.
there are two window batch files.

**1.Startup**

**2.Shutdown.**

By using cmd
if you installed the tomcate in **D Drive**

type on cmd screen

1. **D:**
2. **Cd tomcat\bin**
   then type
   startup.bat for Windows
   and ./startup.sh for Linux
3. 

By clicking them you can start and stop the tomcat.

5.

Final step.

if you start and want to check it.

open a Browser in URL bar type.

```
**HTTP://localhost:8080/**
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to Start and Stop Apache Tomcat Server in Linux and Windows Operating systems. Below is detail facts. Locate the bin folder in your tomcat server and execute the following commands in CMD/ Terminal.

**Linux:**

```
./catalina.sh run
```

Passing "run" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the Tomcat in the **foreground** and **displays the running logs in the same console**. when the console terminal is closed it **will terminate the tomcat**.

```
./catalina.sh start | ./catalina.sh stop
```

Passing "start" argument for catalina.sh --> starts the **Tomcat in the background**. Since in background no issues closing down the terminal. The logs need to be viewed as below: `tail -f $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out`

```
./startup.sh | ./shutdown.sh
```

The last way is firing the startup.sh to start your Tomcat server. If you Vi the script you can see it calls **catalina.sh script passing start as the argument**. This will be running in background as well.

**Windows:**

```
startup.bat // start tomcat server
shutdown.bat // stop tomcat server
```

Answer (score 0):

Change directory to tomcat/bin directory in cmd prompt

> cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin

Run the below command **to start:**

On Linux: >startup.sh

On Windows: >startup.bat

Run these commands **to stop**

On Linux: shutdown.sh

On Windows: shutdown.bat

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.bat` file and write two commands:

```
cd C:\ Path to your tomcat directory \ bin

startup.bat
```

Now on double-click, Tomcat server will start.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded Tomcat and want to stop it (Windows).

1. To stop tomcat

   - run cmd as administrator (I used Cmder)
   - find process ID

tasklist /fi "Imagename eq tomcat*"

```
C:\Users\Admin
tasklist /fi "Imagename eq tomcat*"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
Tomcat8aaw.exe                6376 Console                    1      7,300 K
Tomcat8aa.exe                 5352 Services                   0    124,748 K
```

- stop prosess with pid 6376

C:\Users\Admin

```
taskkill /f /pid 6376
```

SUCCESS: The process with PID 6376 has been terminated.

- stop process with pid 5352

C:\Users\Admin

```
taskkill /f /pid 5352
```

SUCCESS: The process with PID 5352 has been terminated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command
c:\path of you tomcat directory\bin>catalina run