# How to start tomcat server outside netbeans IDE

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I have created an application in Java EE, I have learned how to deploy it in the tomcat server using the manager app or by copying the war file to the webapps folder. Now I can start the tomcat server only  from the Netbeans IDE.

I want to know how to start the apache tomcat server without using the IDE and run my web application from the war file deployed. If I'm headed in the wrong direction please correct me. I'm asking this to gain knowledge of how to deploy the .war file in another server system without using the IDE only the tomcat server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to start stop tomcat server using CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499117/how-to-start-stop-tomcat-server-using-cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell scripts located in "CATALINA_HOME/bin" are the most bare-bones way of getting Tomcat up and running. The two scripts capable of starting Tomcat in this directory are named "catalina" and "startup", with extensions that vary by platform.

Answer (score -1):

In your tomcat installation directory, there would be a startup.bat/sh file which will start the server for you. Moreover you can see the conf folder as well if you want to change any configurations. Whatever war you copy to the webapps folder will be automatically deployed