# Running tomcat with IntelliJ - can't start the server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I can't start the server. It gives me this warning:

> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:1099
>
> 'C:\Users\Keno' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> Disconnected from server
> operable program or batch file.
> The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Try to reinstall Tomcat, make sure you can start it from the command line startup script.

Comment: I installed it and I can run it, but in project it gives me that warning. How to start it from command line?

Comment: It would be much faster for you to just google your question instead of asking here, one on the first search results would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/4499142/104891.

Comment: I added that in path variable, but `startup.bat` is not recognized as a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I downloaded and referenced unzipped folder in Intellij. Solution was to download installation file, install it and referenced installation folder in Intellij. Sorry I was in a rush...

Comment: Unzipped folder works just fine in IntelliJ IDEA, so it's still not clear what was the problem.

Comment: These are the steps I've done:
1) I have downloaded Tomcat zip folder in my documents, I unzipped it and added it in Intellij . When I started the server it gave me those warnings
2) Added path variables as you suggested
3) I downloaded Tomcat installation file, installed it, and referenced installation folder in Intellij. Now it works.