# download jdk1.5.0_14

Tags: classpath, java

I download jdk1.5.0_14 and set environment variable JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH.
Still it is not not working.

How can i download it?

Comment: can you elaborate on "it" (in "it[']s not working") ;-)

Comment: i download jdk1.5.0_14 and set environment variable JAVA_HOME,CLASSPATH,but its not working. Hw can i download jdk1.5.0_14. Which link have to refer for downloading???

Comment: if you downloaded it you already know how to download it. So what's your problem?

Comment: i download jdk1.5.0_14 but its not working. I dont knw where is the problem. Even i set environment variables JAVA_HOME,CLASSPATH.Hw can i solve the problem???

Comment: The file you downloaded is an installation program. Did you run it?

Comment: @neha: and what happened when you executed the installer? Did it execute successfully?

Comment: @neha may i know how did u set JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH.

Comment: @Neha: What are you trying to run? Which application? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check path again. 
For example
In my machine the values are
CLASSPATH as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib;
and JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14

It is your PATH variable 
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin

See [Here](http://objectmix.com/java/392741-javac-not-internal-external-command-error-iamgetting-while-compiling-simple-program.html)

Comment: ya i set the variables JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH. But where is the problem. I cant recognise it???

Comment: describe what's not working. only then we can help find you the problem, if any.

Answer (score 2):

I hope following steps are done:

- Downloading the JDK 5 from this link 
  https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer
  Once you click on this link ,select
  **platform as windows** and select the **offline installation** .
- Once Download is completed(100%) , run the installation file (file will be
  like this
  **jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe**) by double clicking the mouse.
- Once installation is completed , the JDK will be default placed under 
  **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14**
- Now set the **JAVA_HOME** and **CLASSPATH**

---

- Click on Start
- Right Click My Computer from menu
- Select Properties from Drop Down
- Select **Advanced Tab**
- Click on **Environment Variable** button
- Click New button under the user variables Pane or legend
- In the Dialog box under variable name
        type JAVA_HOME and in variable
        value type **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14**
- Click on Ok.
- Click again New button in user variables Pane or legend
- In the Dialog box under variable name type CLASS_PATH 
        and in variable value type
        **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14;
        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\lib**;
- Click on Ok.
- Once done click on Ok and in subsequent windows.

---

- Now Open a cmd prompt , by typing **cmd** from  run menu , found when you click 
  on **Windows Start button**
- once console is opened(a black
  window) , type **java -version** ,
  you may see help   printed in the
  screen  and also type **javac** usage
  will be printed .This means you are
  ready to go.

Comment: Where is this quoted from? Or if it's not quoted you shouldn't be enclosing everything in a blockquote.

Answer (score 0):

Download java 5 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jdk5-jsp-142662.html), install it, [set `JAVA_HOME` environment](http://www.sharpprogrammer.com/2007/05/setting-javahome-variable-in-windows-xp.html)

Comment: when i type javac in command prompt its display message javac is not an internal and external command.

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439641/how-to-fix-internal-or-external-command-errors-in-netbeans)

Comment: @neha kindly go through my steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<java_install_dir>\bin` (most likely `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin`) to your PATH environment variable. Be sure to separate it from everything else with a `;`.